# ToolTip style Template Text not working

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to change the text color of ToolTips through a style template. But changing the ToolTip Foreground property doesn't change the color no matter what I do. I'm almost certain this is because I also have a TextBlock style that's overriding it.

When attempting to retemplate with a new textblock, it has no effect at all. I've spent all day yesterday fiddling with this issue and searching through threads and have found nothing.. Any contribution would be appreciated.

This is the style in my resource dictionary:

```
<!-- TextBlock -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#B2FFFFFF"/>      <!-- ToolTip text color overridden by this -->
</Style>

<!-- ToolTip -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToolTip}}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkBlue"/> <!-- has no effect -->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                <Grid>
                    <Border Name="Border"
                            Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                            Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                            MinWidth="100"
                            MinHeight="30"
                            Margin="0,0,0,50"
                            Background="Beige" 
                            BorderBrush="Black"
                            BorderThickness="1" 
                            CornerRadius="10"/>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="DarkBlue"/> <!-- has not effect -->
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="4"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: More information, please. XAML would be fine.

Comment: What should that `TextBlock` before the `ContentPresenter` do?

Comment: By the way, your style is workinf fine on my machine

Comment: @lokusking  That's my attempt to change the color of the Tooltip text. Correct me if I'm wrong, but a Tooltip has a Textblock in it's default style, which is overridden if you provide a custom style for Textblock as I've done above the Tooltip code. That's there to show that it does nothing, has no effect.

Comment: The Style works... But the color of the text is that of the color in the first Textblock labeled "<!-- TextBlock -->". I don't want that to be the case for a Tooltip, I want a different color.

Comment: Nope. I removed your `TextBlock` in the `ToolTip`. Have one TextBlock made green and Text in `ToolTip` made pink. Works all fine

Comment: But, do you have the first TextBlock style? The overall Textblock style, outside the Tooltip? The two styles are not related.

Comment: Add `Textblock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"` to your `ContentPresenter`

Comment: @ChrisW. Just tried, it didn't work.

Comment: Ah right, wpf. I'll have to look then since what you have should be fine. Anything set at the instance should override the textblock style you have set up top. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem. Yeah that's what puzzles me.. About the instances however, none of that code is in the design view xaml... it's all in the same resource dictionary ( mine is DarkTheme.xaml ), so nothing is being set outside the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out one solution to this issue.

Removing the TargetType from this line:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
```

to read as so:

```
<ControlTemplate >
```

and further down in the ControlTemplate, the textblock should be set like this:

```
<TextBlock  
   Text="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
   Foreground="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
</TextBlock>
```

This allows the text color of a tooltip to be set with the ToolTip's "Foreground" property and is not overridden by other TextBlock styles.